# How can I drop duplicates in pandas without dropping NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe which I query and I want to get only unique values out of a certain column.
I tried to do that executing this code:

```
    database = pd.read_csv(db_file, sep='\t')
    query = database.loc[database[db_specifications[0]].isin(elements)].drop_duplicates(subset=db_specification[1])
```

`db_specification` is just a list containing two columns that I query.
Some of the values are `NaN` and I don't want to consider them duplicates of each other, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by selecting all `NaN` and then drop duplicate on the rest of the dataframe.

```
mask = data.isna().any()
data = pd.concat([data[mask], data[~mask]])
```

Comment: Got an error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isNaN'```